Debezium Cassandra Connector not working in Docker container
I am trying to use the Debezium Cassandra connector in a Docker container using the debezium/connect image. However, the Cassandra connector is not showing up in the list of available connectors.
I have tried the following:

Checked the /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-DBNAME directory in the container, but there is no cassandra directory.

Ran curl -sS localhost:8083/connector-plugins | jq '.' to list the available connectors, but Cassandra is not listed.

Manually created a /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-cassandra directory and added the Cassandra connector JAR files from Maven:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-cassandra/1.7.0.Final/debezium-connector-cassandra-1.7.0.Final-plugin.tar.gz
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-cassandra/1.7.0.Final/debezium-connector-cassandra-1.7.0.Final.jar

But restarting the container did not help.


Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
